# passing information from cURL code to DOM Parser and viceversa

Tags: php, dom, curl

I’ve got a PHP script that performs a login into a device. The login operation returns a cookie and all this is performed with cURL instructions.

Next step is: I have to go around a JavaScript ALERT button that appears after I’ve modified some fields.

I’ve found out this page (www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/426740-using-visual-basic-applications-close-internet-explorer-message-box-popup.html) where VBA code modifies the HTML page, hence neutralizing the ALERT window.

In the quest for a solution entirely within the PHP realm, I’ve found the "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser" library that helps achieve that. And indeed I wrote some sample code that, after loading the file version of the page I get after login, it modifies the page as the VBA code would do.

The problem I’m now facing is: how to bridge the cURL solution with the DOM Parser one, and that’s where I’m seeking the advice of this community. Thanks.

Robert

Comment: Well, I know that the curl_exec ($ch) returns the page, which in tour I can pass to DOM Parser for modification.
But how do I pass the updated page back to cURL for posting?

Comment: This sounds like you're trying to bypass someone else's GUI and seems somewhat suspicious to me ...

Comment: Nothing to worry about, simply automating some device field service operations.

Comment: oki - if you want to pass the data back, just create a new POST string, with the URL encoded document data as a POST var, and throw it at a new cURL instance and curl_exec that..? I feel I may have misunderstood something - cURL basically works like HTML forms but without the visual forms themselves.

Comment: Let's say I've got the HTML page (<html> ... </html>) in a string + the cookie of my current session saved somewhere. I want to write (is it POST?) the "string", which is my updated page, back to the device using a CURL instruction within my current session. How do I do that?

Comment: It would be easier if I could use CURL to modify an anchor element in the page. But while I know how to modify a "field" (a curl_setopt with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS and "ID_name=value"), I don't know how to modify an HTML "element". That's it.

Comment: Your cookie will probably only hold the session id, the session data will reside on the server which set the cookie (where you logged in) - IF the server allows transparent session ids you could simply affix the session id to the GET part of the URL - something like `curl_setopt($hCurl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://...etc.../?PHPSID=$_COOKIE['PHPSID'])`